# MySQL Query with Left Join, Order By and Limit and other joins

Tags: mysql

Trying to get data and subdata from multiple tables. The important part here is the joining of the student_passports data/table. Everything else is working fine (though if you have hints on how to improve the query, that would always be appreciated).
I'm essentially trying to return a single row, the 'most recent' passport in existence for a student.
I've tried multiple approaches but am not winning. The first seems like the most logical approach. I've laid them all out below...

This seems like the correct approach but Left Join returns a bunch of NULL values (with the exception of 1 the returned rows actually having values for passport_number and passport_expiry_date):

```
SELECT 
    students.id AS sid,
    bursary_administrator_student.bursary_administrator_reference, students.student_name, students.student_surname,
    students.id_number, stud_pass.passport_number, stud_pass.passport_expiry_date,
    
    (SELECT STATUS FROM student_bursary_statuses 
            INNER JOIN student_bursaries ON student_bursaries.id=student_bursary_statuses.student_bursary_id
            INNER JOIN students ON students.id=student_bursaries.student_id
    WHERE student_id=sid AND (status_start<=NOW() AND (status_end>=NOW() OR status_end IS NULL)) LIMIT 1) AS STATUS,

    (SELECT contact_detail FROM student_contact_details 
    INNER JOIN students ON student_contact_details.`student_id`=students.id
    INNER JOIN contact_detail_types ON student_contact_details.`contact_detail_type_id`=contact_detail_types.id
    WHERE `primary`=1 AND contact_detail_type='Mobile ZA' AND student_id=sid LIMIT 1) AS primary_mobile,
    
    (SELECT contact_detail FROM student_contact_details
    INNER JOIN students ON student_contact_details.`student_id`=students.id
    INNER JOIN contact_detail_types ON student_contact_details.`contact_detail_type_id`=contact_detail_types.id
    WHERE `primary`=1 AND contact_detail_type='Email' AND student_id=sid LIMIT 1) AS primary_email
    
FROM students
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT student_id, passport_number, passport_expiry_date FROM student_passports 
    ORDER BY passport_expiry_date DESC LIMIT 1) stud_pass ON students.id=stud_pass.student_id
INNER JOIN bursary_administrator_student ON students.id=bursary_administrator_student.student_id
WHERE bursary_administrator_student.bursary_administrator_id=1
ORDER BY students.id
```

I tried this Left Join, but takes 30s to execute (not a large db, just several hundred rows in each table) and ends up returning 132,148 rows when its supposed to be around 360 or so - so clearly returning a multiple:

```
SELECT 
    students.id AS sid,
    bursary_administrator_student.bursary_administrator_reference, students.student_name, students.student_surname,
    students.id_number, student_passports.passport_number, student_passports.passport_expiry_date,
    
    (SELECT STATUS FROM student_bursary_statuses 
    INNER JOIN student_bursaries ON student_bursaries.id=student_bursary_statuses.student_bursary_id
    INNER JOIN students ON students.id=student_bursaries.student_id
    WHERE student_id=sid AND (status_start<=NOW() AND (status_end>=NOW() OR status_end IS NULL)) LIMIT 1) AS STATUS,

    (SELECT contact_detail FROM student_contact_details 
    INNER JOIN students ON student_contact_details.`student_id`=students.id
    INNER JOIN contact_detail_types ON student_contact_details.`contact_detail_type_id`=contact_detail_types.id
    WHERE `primary`=1 AND contact_detail_type='Mobile ZA' AND student_id=sid LIMIT 1) AS primary_mobile,
    
    (SELECT contact_detail FROM student_contact_details
    INNER JOIN students ON student_contact_details.`student_id`=students.id
    INNER JOIN contact_detail_types ON student_contact_details.`contact_detail_type_id`=contact_detail_types.id
    WHERE `primary`=1 AND contact_detail_type='Email' AND student_id=sid LIMIT 1) AS primary_email
    
FROM students
LEFT JOIN student_passports ON students.`id`= (SELECT student_passports.`student_id` FROM student_passports WHERE student_passports.`student_id`=students.id ORDER BY passport_expiry_date DESC LIMIT 1)

INNER JOIN bursary_administrator_student ON students.id=bursary_administrator_student.student_id
WHERE bursary_administrator_student.bursary_administrator_id=1
ORDER BY students.id
```

"Works", but this is dirty and prone to data errors no doubt when passport_expiry_date has the same value for multiple rows:

```
SELECT 
    students.id AS sid,
    bursary_administrator_student.bursary_administrator_reference, students.student_name, students.student_surname,
    students.id_number, 
    
    (SELECT student_passports.passport_number FROM student_passports
    INNER JOIN students ON student_passports.`student_id`=students.id
    WHERE student_id=sid ORDER BY passport_expiry_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS passport_number,

    (SELECT student_passports.passport_expiry_date FROM student_passports
    INNER JOIN students ON student_passports.`student_id`=students.id
    WHERE student_id=sid ORDER BY passport_expiry_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS passport_expiry_date,

    (SELECT STATUS FROM student_bursary_statuses 
    INNER JOIN student_bursaries ON student_bursaries.id=student_bursary_statuses.student_bursary_id
    INNER JOIN students ON students.id=student_bursaries.student_id
    WHERE student_id=sid AND (status_start<=NOW() AND (status_end>=NOW() OR status_end IS NULL)) LIMIT 1) AS STATUS,

    (SELECT contact_detail FROM student_contact_details 
    INNER JOIN students ON student_contact_details.`student_id`=students.id
    INNER JOIN contact_detail_types ON student_contact_details.`contact_detail_type_id`=contact_detail_types.id
    WHERE `primary`=1 AND contact_detail_type='Mobile ZA' AND student_id=sid LIMIT 1) AS primary_mobile,
    
    (SELECT contact_detail FROM student_contact_details
    INNER JOIN students ON student_contact_details.`student_id`=students.id
    INNER JOIN contact_detail_types ON student_contact_details.`contact_detail_type_id`=contact_detail_types.id
    WHERE `primary`=1 AND contact_detail_type='Email' AND student_id=sid LIMIT 1) AS primary_email
    
FROM students
INNER JOIN bursary_administrator_student ON students.id=bursary_administrator_student.student_id
WHERE bursary_administrator_student.bursary_administrator_id=1
ORDER BY students.id
```

// Edit: Here's a better version of the third/above solution where I select the ID of the matching student_passport, then use that id to select the relevant two fields of the appropriate record. Still think there has to be a better way to do this though:

```
SELECT 
students.id AS sid,
bursary_administrator_student.bursary_administrator_reference, students.student_name, students.student_surname,
students.id_number, 

(SELECT student_passports.id FROM student_passports
INNER JOIN students ON student_passports.`student_id`=students.id
WHERE student_id=sid ORDER BY passport_expiry_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS student_passports_id,

    (SELECT student_passports.passport_number FROM student_passports
    INNER JOIN students ON student_passports.`student_id`=students.id
    WHERE student_passports.id=student_passports_id ORDER BY passport_expiry_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS passport_number,

    (SELECT student_passports.passport_expiry_date FROM student_passports
    INNER JOIN students ON student_passports.`student_id`=students.id
    WHERE student_passports.id=student_passports_id ORDER BY passport_expiry_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS passport_expiry_date,

(SELECT STATUS FROM student_bursary_statuses 
INNER JOIN student_bursaries ON student_bursaries.id=student_bursary_statuses.student_bursary_id
INNER JOIN students ON students.id=student_bursaries.student_id
WHERE student_id=sid AND (status_start<=NOW() AND (status_end>=NOW() OR status_end IS NULL)) LIMIT 1) AS STATUS,

(SELECT contact_detail FROM student_contact_details 
INNER JOIN students ON student_contact_details.`student_id`=students.id
INNER JOIN contact_detail_types ON student_contact_details.`contact_detail_type_id`=contact_detail_types.id
WHERE `primary`=1 AND contact_detail_type='Mobile ZA' AND student_id=sid LIMIT 1) AS primary_mobile,

(SELECT contact_detail FROM student_contact_details
INNER JOIN students ON student_contact_details.`student_id`=students.id
INNER JOIN contact_detail_types ON student_contact_details.`contact_detail_type_id`=contact_detail_types.id
WHERE `primary`=1 AND contact_detail_type='Email' AND student_id=sid LIMIT 1) AS primary_email

FROM students
INNER JOIN bursary_administrator_student ON students.id=bursary_administrator_student.student_id
WHERE bursary_administrator_student.bursary_administrator_id=1
ORDER BY students.id
```

Comment: It would help if you qualified all the column names with the table name/alias they belong to, like primary, contact_detail_type, student_id and sid in the subqueries.

Comment: Consider simplifying the problem, and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example